# I want a trigger to be able to change value if a date is less than current date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my trigger but i keep getting this error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_date
    BEFORE INSERT ON rooms
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE rooms
  SET end_date = NULL, start_date = NULL, availabilty=y WHERE end_date < curdate();
END;
```

Comment: Make `availability = 'y'`

Comment: I already did that, still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql you can't issue DML statements against a table you apply trigger to. But you can modify values (only for `BEFORE` event) of columns of a record that is being inserted (or updated) using `NEW` keyword.

Try

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_date
BEFORE INSERT ON rooms
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.end_date < CURDATE() THEN
    SET NEW.end_date = NULL, NEW.start_date = NULL, NEW.availability ='y';
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac1b32/2)** demo.

Answer (score 1):

`y` is probably not a column in your table. If you mean the string `'y'`, you should put it in single quotes.

```
availabilty='y'
```

Also note that availabilty contains a typo. The correct English spelling is availability, but of course I don't know your column names.

Comment: I changed the y like you said but i still get the same error and yes availabilty is my colomn name its deliberate do you think I should put the Null values into quotes aswell?

Comment: No, the null values should not be quoted.